# What are side chain order parameters?

Tags: biochemistry, structural-biology

I was reading an [article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jmb.2008.05.006):

> We first compared experimental (S 2 exp) and computed (S 2 calc) side-chain order parameters using the simplest approximation of side-chain conformational variability, where motions are only allowed within the rotamer well of the side-chain conformation observed in the crystal structure

Now I am wondering what side-chain order parameters are.

Comment: That nomenclature is from the [model-free approach from Lipari and Szabo](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00381a009)